# How to dynamically remove field in custom form using AJAX

Tags: entities, ajax

Based on the "Add-more button (with graceful degradation)" example available in Drupal examples module I have created a form that can add fields dynamically using AJAX, and now i want to add a separate Remove button to each of those fields so that i can remove individual fields (not just the last field).

Decrementing the number of fields and rebuilding the form only removes the last field in the form.

What's the Drupal way of doing this? and what would be the best approach to achieve my requirement?

Comment: check which button was clicked, only remove the row that matches, then re-key the array from 0 again

Comment: Thank you Clive, can you please elaborate this little more?

Comment: Not easily, how exactly you accomplish that really depends on what your code looks like. Some hints though: each 'remove' button will need a specific, unique `#name` property set on it, so you can check `$form_state['triggering_element']` in the ajax callback. If you append a numeric index to that `#name`, you can use it to identify the index of the element array that you need to remove. Hope that helps, if you get stuck just edit the question to add the relevant portions of code and describe what it's doing/not doing etc